# C++ Class output incorrect

Tags: c++, class, output

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Pyramid{

    public:
        Pyramid();
        void set_surfaceArea(double, double, double);
        void set_volume(double, double);
        double get_surfaceArea();
        double get_volume();
        void print_sufraceArea();
        void print_volume();


    private:
        double height,
                     sideLength,
                     perimeter,
                     baseArea,
                     surfaceArea,
                     volume;
};

Pyramid::Pyramid(){
    height = 0;
    baseArea = 0;
    perimeter = 0;
    sideLength = 0;
}

void Pyramid::set_surfaceArea(double baseArea, double sideLength, double perimeter){
    baseArea = baseArea;
    sideLength = sideLength;
    perimeter = perimeter;
}

void Pyramid::set_volume(double baseArea, double height){
    baseArea = baseArea;
    height = height;
}

double Pyramid::get_surfaceArea(){
    return (1/2) * baseArea * perimeter * sideLength;  

}

double Pyramid::get_volume(){
    x = (1/3) * baseArea * height;
    return x;
}


int main(){
    double height,
                 test,
                 sideLength,
                 perimeter,
                 baseArea;
  cout << "Enter height: ";
  cin >> height;
  cout << "Enter side length: ";
  cin >> sideLength;
  cout << "Enter perimeter: ";
  cin >> perimeter;
  cout <<"Enter base area: ";
  cin >> baseArea;

  Pyramid x;

    x.set_surfaceArea(baseArea, sideLength, perimeter);
    x.set_volume(baseArea, height);

    test = x.get_volume();
    cout << "test: " << test << endl;
}
```

When I run this code (and enter numbers for input), I get the output of "test: 0". This code is my first try at making a class from scratch. I'm sure someone can easily point out why my output is giving me '0' regardless of what I put in.

Thanks!

Comment: in `set_surfaceArea` you set the variables equal to themselves. Just rename the arguments to something besides the same as the class members, and try again.

Comment: But that's the name of the input variables I set. Should I set them to something else?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: ...so did that work?

Comment: Testing in a few and will let you know

Comment: Apparently we need to make the [MCVE] requirement more prominent. Nobody's posting them any more. Sigh.

Comment: As i'm new here, could you explain, Lightness? I'd like to be more specific in my next post. Thanks! Still waiting to test...

Comment: Also, your suggestion ocket8888 did not work unfortunately.

Comment: k, I can tell you more tomorrow or maybe not till monday

Comment: Why not adopt using the prefix ` m_` for member variables and avoid this problem?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was able to reproduce without any effort (except for a single compilation issue where X was not defined). I agree, it would have been nice to have gotten input values and an expected result. (e.g. 1.0;1.1;1.2;1.3 with result 0.4333333) However in this case, it wasn't needed.

Comment: Surely things like ` baseArea = baseArea;` shouts to you that you are doing something wrong?

Comment: @JVApen: You're missing the point. Sure, sometimes it looks like we can make the MCVE ourselves. _But the OP still is required to do it._ You can't guarantee that there isn't some facet the OP has failed to mention or didn't realise was relevant. If there is, everything here immediately becomes moot. So, no matter how simple it looks, MCVE is a **requirement**. By definition, it has to be. It also makes the question to be of acceptable quality, searchability and _re-usability_ for continued existence on this site. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do apologize for the inconvenience and I will learn from this. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is actually very clear. Your code is suffering from having 2 variables with the exact same name, where the scope is important in order to know which variable is actually used.

An example: You have defined 'height' as a class member, though also as a method parameter for set_volume. So if you write `height = height;` you actually are doing a self-assignment. For this specific example, my compiler (clang) is warning for this with the error message `explicitly assigning value of variable of type 'double' to itself` (I expect other compilers to generate something similar)

To fix this problem, you'll have to rename one of the variables. I would suggest renaming the class members to either `_height`, `m_height` or `mHeight` in order to clearly indicate that this is a member. (Examples are based upon existing style guides)

So, as soon as you've fixed this problem, the members will get a different value from 0, however the result is still the same as you have written: `(1/3)`

This code will always evaluate to 0, as you are doing an integer division. This is defined as dividing an integer by another integer, which results in the floored value of the result. So, in this case 0.333 gets floored to 0. Replacing this code by `(1./3.)` fixes this issue.

Comment: Thank you for a post that wasn't condescending. I will most likely use `m_variable` from now on. My code is now working! Thanks again.